# Restoring a wiki website from a SQLite backup

Tags: xampp, media, mediawiki, wiki

A portable wiki I had setup was physically damaged in the flashdrive it resided in. Thankfully, I made backups of the files found in "G:\XAMPP\htdocs\wiki\cache". I'm only having difficulty restoring their use in the new wiki.

I set things up using this tutorial and haven't made any changes with the exception of minor wiki extensions. http://lifehacker.com/354005/run-your-personal-wikipedia-from-a-usb-stick

I found and backed up two files in the 'cache' folder prior to this.

- `.htaccess` (which I'm assuming can be easily replaced) [1 KB]
- `wikiname.sqlite` (is where I hope most pages are stored) [7,863 KB]

I sincerely hope that the second contains most of the old wiki's content. I was able to read some of it by opening the file with a .txt editor. Unfortunately, the .sqlite file was mostly unreadable via that program.

Answer (score 0):

To read data from a sqlite database you should use a SQLite browser; [Google will help you](https://www.google.de/#q=sqlite+browser) find one.

So, in case the database is complete and not damaged, you should be able to restore your wiki. First: make another copy of your backup, if something went completely wrong :) After it, setup a new wiki with the latest stable version (btw: what version did you used for your wiki?), at the moment MediaWiki 1.24.2, and use sqlite as a database connection.

After creating a new database file, replace it with your backup and you should be able to access your wiki. Maybe, depending on what version you used before, you need to run the update script (in your console with `php maintenance/update.php --quick` or with the update script in your web browser http:/yourwiki/mw-config/).

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! 

I was so worried that I was alone on this. With all the esoteric instructions on the MediaWiki website, and the unbelievable amount of out-of-date tutorials, I thought my work was forever lost.

Comment: I've updated the link. It should work now. 

I used the one found on sqlitebrowser.org, but I couldn't figure out how to view page content after opening the database. It lists ar_id, ar_namespace, ar_title, etc. But does not display any of the text information written on the original wiki. Is there a way to view that data here, or do I have to access it via the new wiki?

Comment: I copied the database directly from the original wiki, and uploaded it to Google Drive. I haven't modified it in the slightest; only replacing it with the most recent wiki edits.

Comment: One of the problems I've been having is setting up the wiki in the same way I had at the start. I have no idea what wiki version I used then, and I'm not certain of the XAMPP version either. However, I can tell you that the .htaccess file I have backed up was created on 11/20/2014. The day I started the original wiki. After posting this, I'll look for versions from that time-frame.

Comment: Does the new wiki have to match the specific naming properties of the old one?

Comment: Important is, that your wiki using the old database, all othe configuration settings can be adjusted if needed. The goal is to access the wiki content, which should be possible without the exact setup you had before. Just try to setup a new wiki with a new database and replace the new db file with the old one and check, what happens :) btw: it should be possible to view the text of all wiki pages, it should be in a table revision or so, but it's definitely no fun to read the content there, ot would be easier to access the content through a wiki :)